# Solving Equations System - variables assignment

Tags: matlab, struct

I'm using the solve function in order to solve 7 equations with 7 variables.
The function works good, but after the equations are solved I want to save the variables as a matrix. The problem is, it saves it as a struct.
For example:

```
syms x y        
S = solve(x==3 , y==5-x);       
y1(1,1) = S.y;
```

`y1` is a struct. Why?
How can i save it as a matrix?

Comment: I believe you can use `c = struct2cell(s)` in order to convert structure `(s)` to cell array `c` in matlab. Check out this link: http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/struct2cell.html I hope it helps!

Comment: doesnt work...but double is :)

Answer (score 1):

`S.y` is a symbolic variable, you have to [convert it to a numeric](http://www.mathworks.fr/fr/help/symbolic/double.html) if you want to save it as a numerical result.

E.g.

```
y1(1,1) = double(S.y);
```